# How can I run my docker container with installed Nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, docker, boot2docker, dockerfile

I have docker image with `Dockerfile`, that successfully build with `docker build .` command. The `Dockerfile` content is:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx php5 php5-fpm
ADD . /code
```

How can I run my docker container to see that `Nginx` is work?

UPDATE: When I try to use next Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx php5 php5-fpm
RUN sudo echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
CMD service php5-fpm start && nginx
```

It build successfully with `docker build -t my/nginx .`, but when I enter `docker run --rm -ti my/nginx` command, my terminal not response:

[image]

Comment: off-topic: any reason why you're running php fpm and nginx in the same container? it's an anti-pattern in docker (like install sshd so you can view logs). also docker have reference images for both (read: you'll get support if you need it)

Comment: @booyaa Thanks! I'm newbie in Docker and it's hard to work with a few containers at the same time. So now I want to get work state of my first container, and if it works, I'll try to split Nginx and php-fpm processes to separate containers. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you build the image you probably want to specify the image name with `-t` option.

```
docker build -t my/nginx .
```

To run a container use the `run` command

```
docker run --rm -ti my/nginx
```

You probably should add the following command to your Dockerfile

```
CMD ["nginx"]
```

Or with php5-fpm

```
CMD service php5-fpm start && nginx
```

UPDATE.
You should run nginx as daemon off. Add the following to your Dockerfile after installing nginx.

```
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Update2.

`-ti` option in run allows you to check the log messages if any.
Usually you should run a container in background using `-d` instead of `-ti`.
You can attach to a running container using the `attach` command.

You may also check [docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/) to see how to stop and remove a container and other commands.

Comment: Thanks, I added `CMD service php5-fpm start && nginx` line at the end of Docker file, then successfully build image and when try to run container had an error: `/bin/sh: 1: nginx: not found`

Comment: If I use `CMD ["nginx"]` I had a next error: `exec: "nginx": executable file not found in $PATH
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 565c2cbc8d60c098bcac276d625390e34ac20f4e4d502723985934ec1c048fa8: [8] System error: exec: "nginx": executable file not found in $PATH`

Comment: I don't know what is in your /code. Try to comment it out and run without it. I also updated my answer.

Comment: I removed this line, but now when I execute `run` command, my terminal not response more. I also update my question

Comment: Thanks, it works with `-d` key. In `docker ps` I can see my run container.